# How to delete all divs with at least one child using jquery?

Tags: jquery, parent-child, traversal

I want to delete all the divs who has at least one child using jquery. So for this example I need to delete the divs containing paragraph with 'hello' and 'world'. Can any one please help ?

```
<div style="background:#FF0000;height:200px;width:200px;">
<p> Hello </p>
</div>
<div style="background:#00FF00;height:200px;width:200px; ">
</div>
<div style="background:#0000FF;height:200px;width:200px;">
</div>
<div style="background:#AAAA3A;height:200px;width:200px;">
<p>World </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `:has` selector

```
$('div:has(*)').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9GdmN/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length > 0) $(this).remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EX8EN/)**

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . Is there any way to select all the divs with at least one child by one command ? I want to avoid this each iteration.